# ¿Por qué al sumar dos numeros en javascript, la nueva variable la muestra como string?

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo un programa que me calcula una variable "letra", entonces, para hallar el importe mensual, multiplico esa letra por un vector mensual que está en un array, es decir al final el importe de cada mes lo guardo en otro array, y quedaría por ejemplo, letra_por_cuota[0]=letra*vector_por_cuota[0]; donde la letra por cuota es el importe mensual y el vector por cuota es el vector mensual. Lo que quiero hallar es el importe total, pero al sumar todos los numeros del array de letra_por_cuota, me da un string, algo asi como si quisiera sumar 1+1 y en ves de darme 2, me da como respuesta 11.
les dejo un pantallazo de lo que he hecho.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven en la imagen, en la parte de abajo del total pagado me aparece eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si necesitan el codig, me avisan para ponerlo, pero es muy grande.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: el código directamente involucrado en la operación matemática que esta fallando va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Perdon, ya lo solucioné, solo debia ponerle parseFloat a cada array de letra, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué editor de texto usas?

Comment: visual studio code